# How can I speed up getting a directory's content in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, file, optimization, explorer

I've been working on a "File Explorer" project for a while now as a learning project and to have some fun with trying new ways to code. It's been going quite well so far and I'm very pleased with what I've managed to figure out. Where I'm hitting a bit of a roadblock is with speed. In windows explorer, if you go into a new directory it will (depending of course on version and other variables) only take a few moments to list all the files and subdirectories. My application on the other hand, is still decently quick, but will very noticeably slow down the more items there are in the directory.

I have this function which I call in my "Navigate" function. Which I believe is where I will likely find the culprit and solution:

```
    private void GetDirectoryContent(string directory)
    {
        txtPath.Text = directory;

        currentDirectoryFiles.Clear();
        filesList.Items.Clear();

        int longestName = 0;
        int longestType = 0;
        foreach (string item in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
        {
            int nameLength = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1).Length;
            
            if (nameLength > longestName) longestName = nameLength;
            if ("Folder".Length > longestType) longestType = "Folder".Length;
        }

        foreach (string item in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
        {
            int nameLength = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1).Length;
            
            if (nameLength > longestName) longestName = nameLength;
            if (GetFileType(item).Length > longestType) longestType = GetFileType(item).Length;
        }

        filesList.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        filesList.View = View.Details;
        filesList.Columns.Clear();
        filesList.Columns.Add("Name", longestName * 8);
        filesList.Columns.Add("Date Modified", 160);
        filesList.Columns.Add("Type", longestType * 8);

        foreach (string item in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
        {
            string name = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            
            smallImageList.Images.Add(new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Xplorer.ico"));
            ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(name, smallImageList.Images.Count - 1); // Name
            row.SubItems.Add(Directory.GetLastWriteTime(item).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)); // Date Modified
            row.SubItems.Add("Folder"); // Type
            row.Tag = "Folder";
            currentDirectoryFiles.Add(item);
            filesList.Items.Add(row);
        }

        foreach (string item in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
        {
            string name = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            
            smallImageList.Images.Add(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(item) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
            ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(name, smallImageList.Images.Count - 1); // Name
            row.SubItems.Add(File.GetLastWriteTime(item).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)); // Date Modified
            row.SubItems.Add(GetFileType(item)); // Type 
            row.Tag = "File";
            currentDirectoryFiles.Add(item);
            filesList.Items.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

I'm still a newbie programmer so I know a lot of this code could probably be condensed, but I don't actually know how so that's what my main question is. How can I condense/optimize this function to speed up the results (and just to follow better practices for later projects.)

Please let me know if I left any details out you might need, as I said I'm still fairly new and don't know a ton about what might be helpful to know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well to start with, you're calling both `Directory.GetFiles` and `Directory.GetDirectories` twice. I suggest you call each of them just once, and store the results in variables that you can use in your foreach loops. (I'd also suggest using `Path.GetFilename` instead of using manual string manipulation.)

Comment: Why do you call these things multiple times? Also worth noting, EnumerateFiles doesn't wait until its collected everyfile system entry before it starts returning listings.. Profile to see where your slow points actually are; I can imagine the image handling bits might be impacting somewhat

Comment: Please put the solution in the answer space below.

Comment: It makes sense also to suspend/resume control's layout while adding elements to it. For instance, if `filesList` is `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox`, you can do it via `filesList.BeginUpdate()` and `filesList.EndUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone! This is a new function, it works very quickly!

```
private void GetDirectoryContent(string directory)
{
    txtPath.Text = directory;

    currentDirectoryFiles.Clear();
    filesList.Items.Clear();

    string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory).ToArray();
    string[] directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory).ToArray();

    filesList.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
    filesList.View = View.Details;
    filesList.Columns.Clear();
    filesList.Columns.Add("Name", 250);
    filesList.Columns.Add("Date Modified", 160);
    filesList.Columns.Add("Type", 125);

    foreach (string item in directories)
    {
        string name = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        
        smallImageList.Images.Add(new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Xplorer.ico"));
        ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(name, smallImageList.Images.Count - 1); // Name
        row.SubItems.Add(Directory.GetLastWriteTime(item).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)); // Date Modified
        row.SubItems.Add("Folder"); // Type
        row.Tag = "Folder";
        currentDirectoryFiles.Add(item);
        filesList.Items.Add(row);
    }

    foreach (string item in files)
    {
        string name = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        
        smallImageList.Images.Add(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(item) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
        ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(name, smallImageList.Images.Count - 1); // Name
        row.SubItems.Add(File.GetLastWriteTime(item).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)); // Date Modified
        row.SubItems.Add(GetFileType(item)); // Type 
        row.Tag = "File";
        currentDirectoryFiles.Add(item);
        filesList.Items.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: `smallImageList.Images.Add(new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Xplorer.ico"));` is adding the same icon over and over.  You only need one copy of it, then re-use the index number of it for all entries that need that same icon. So add it BEFORE the loop, determine its index value, then pass that same index value to each directory entry.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a good choice for a learning project :)
Maybe use DirectoryInfo instead of searching with the strings. It would make it a easier for you and it's probably a little bit faster

```
private void GetDirectoryContent(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    //you could also leave it as string and write var dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory); 
    /*...*/
    foreach (DirectoryInfo item in directory.GetDirectories())
    {
        string name = item.Name; //.FullName would include the path   
        smallImageList.Images.Add(new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Xplorer.ico"));
        ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(name, smallImageList.Images.Count - 1); 
        row.SubItems.Add(item.LastWriteTime.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
        row.SubItems.Add("Folder"); // Type
        row.Tag = "Folder";
        currentDirectoryFiles.Add(item);
        filesList.Items.Add(row);
    }
 
    foreach (FileInfo item in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        /* also knows its name, extension, last write time, ...*/
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

If you get a little farther and feel comfortable maybe also try a bit of new stuff. I think usefull stuff for your learning project would be things like IEnumerables or recursion (it's really useful for treelike structures like the filesystem)